How to write data into binaryOutput object of a BACnet device using System.IO.Bacnet library in C#
bacnetClient.Start();

BacnetAddress deviceAddress = new BacnetAddress(BacnetAddressTypes.IP, "10.20.30.250:47808");

BacnetObjectId objectId = new BacnetObjectId(BacnetObjectTypes.OBJECT_BINARY_OUTPUT, 2);

IList<BacnetValue> values;
         
bool success = bacnetClient.ReadPropertyRequest(deviceAddress, objectId, BacnetPropertyIds.PROP_PRESENT_VALUE, out values);

if (success)
{
      string presentValue = values[0].Value.ToString();
      Console.WriteLine($"Present Value: {presentValue}");
}
else
{
      Console>writeLine("Error occurred while reading from the device.")
}

uint value = 1;

IList<BacnetValue> valtowrite = new BacnetValue[1] { new BacnetValue(value) };
                       
bool successWrite = bacnetClient.WritePropertyRequest(deviceAddress, objectId, BacnetPropertyIds.PROP_PRESENT_VALUE, valtowrite );
if (successWrite)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\nSuccessfully updated the status for OBJECT_BINARY_OUTPUT 2");
    bool successRead = bacnetClient.ReadPropertyRequest(deviceAddress, objectId, BacnetPropertyIds.PROP_PRESENT_VALUE, out values);

    if (successRead)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\nSuccessfully updated the status for OBJECT_BINARY_OUTPUT 2");
    }
    else { 
        Console.WriteLine("\n!! Error occured when reading from BACnet device. !!");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n !! Error occurred while writing to the bacnet device. !!");
}

In my program, first I have started the connection and read the value from this same object and it works perfectly fine. But when I try to write values, I get an error saying

System.Exception: Reject from device, reason: INVALID_TAG
at System.IO.BACnet.BacnetClient.WritePropertyRequest(BacnetAddress adr,BacnetObjectId objectId, BacnetPropertyIds propertyId, IEnumerable`1 valueList, Byte invokeId)

I want to write (update) the value of the BinaryOutput object to change its status (Active/Inactive)

I have absolutely-zero knowledge about Bacnet, but the error looks like it's because you're using BacnetPropertyIds.PROP_PRESENT_VALUE to set a value, whereas PROP_PRESENT_VALUE seems to be an op to getting a value, right?

Present value is a property that BACnet objects have and to identify that present value property we use PROP_PRESENT_VALUE as the id to identify it. Therefore BacnetPropertyIds.PROP_PRESENT_VALUE means that I'm going to access BacnetProperty: present value. After that we should provide the value we are going to update into that property we declare.

It's probably worth saying where/how you got the (BACnet) library; so if responders are experienced using a multitude of other libraries, they can consider setting-up a sample in order to answer your question/issue (- as well as it might assist a new person appreciate knowing about this library as a possible option to adopt for themselves).
Have you tried looking at the encoded on-the-wire request using Wireshark?  It might help others (who are unfamiliar with the library) if they can see the encoded bytes (/let others see the problem from a different angle).

It sounds like it might be the wrong data-type being encoded, upon reading the property, have to checked that the type of "values[0].Value" is a 'uint'/'UInt32', and not a 'bool' or 'UInt16' (?).

I somehow got it worked.
using System.IO.BACnet;

BacnetClient bacnetClient = new BacnetClient(new BacnetIpUdpProtocolTransport(0xBAC0, false));

//start the connection with the network, which is connected with bacnet device
bacnetClient.Start();

// Define the BACnet address of the device
BacnetAddress deviceAddress = new BacnetAddress(BacnetAddressTypes.IP, "10.20.30.250:47808");

// Define the object identifier (e.g., Analog Input 1)
BacnetObjectId objectId = new BacnetObjectId(BacnetObjectTypes.OBJECT_BINARY_OUTPUT, 2);

UInt32 newStatus = 1;

// create BacnetValue variable to write.
BacnetValue valueToWrite = new BacnetValue(BacnetApplicationTags.BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED, newStatus);

//Sends a request to write the Present_Value property of the specified object.
bool successWrite = bacnetClient.WritePropertyRequest(deviceAddress, objectId, BacnetPropertyIds.PROP_PRESENT_VALUE, new[] { valueToWrite });
if (successWrite)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\nSuccessfully updated the status for OBJECT_BINARY_OUTPUT 2");
}
else
{    
Console.WriteLine("\n !! Error occurred while writing to the bacnet device. !!");
}

First, I created the BACnet client using the BACnet/IP protocol with the default BACnet port (0xBAC0 = 47808). And 'false' in there indicated that communication is not using broadcast.
Then I started the connection with 'bacnetClient.Start();'.
In 3rd line, I have indicated the IP address of the target BACnet device alongside its port.
In the 4th line, I have declared the object I want to read/write by stating ObjectType and ObjectInstance (in this case I'm targeting a Binary Output object whose instance number is 2).
'UInt32 newStatus = 1;' my 'writeValue' which uses the data type UInt32.
Normally BACnet objects use Array to represent Present Value property.
'BacnetValue valueToWrite = new BacnetValue(BacnetApplicationTags.BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED, newStatus);' So, in this line, I have created the BACnetValue array which uses the ENUMERATED data type. and store my 'writeValue' in it.
After that, I sent a request to write into the device using WritePropertyRequest().
So in this 'WritePropertyRequest' we should indicate the 'target device IP, the target object type and its instance, the property we are going to read/write (in this case I'm going to write 'presentValue' property), and the value we are writing as an array.
Hope this explanation is clear.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
